# RegEx : Match all lines except for a specific sub-string

Tags: python, regex

Below is the list :

```
cf-ab1
cf-bc2
cf-ab1-hotfix
cf-bc2-hotfix
cf-ab1-canary
cf-cd1-staging
cf-cd1-staging2
cf-cd1
cf-cd1-sic-staging
cf-cd1-sagdf-staging
```

I would like to match everything except for `cf-cd1-staging, cf-cd1-staging2 and cf-ab1-canary` 
I am running the below regex :

```
 ^((?!canary|staging).)*$
```

But these ideally matches all lines that doesnot contain staging and canary..! which should not be my desired o/p.

Could you please help here..!? because my desired matches should be :

```
cf-ab1
cf-bc2
cf-ab1-hotfix
cf-bc2-hotfix
cf-cd1
cf-cd1-sic-staging
cf-cd1-sagdf-staging
```

Regards,

Rohith

Comment: Can you explain in plain English what you want the distinguishing factor to be? At the moment, it's not clear what the rules for a general solution would be

Comment: Try `^(?!.*(ab1-canary|cd1-staging)).*$`

Comment: Looks cool..! but is there a way that i use it in GO; because it works only for pyhton; for GO it says : `Template variables could not be initialized: error parsing query: error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!` at line 1, char 70    `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : -

```
import re

lines = ["cf-ab1", "cf-bc2", "cf-ab1-hotfix", "cf-bc2-hotfix", "cf-ab1-canary", "cf- 
cd1-staging", "cf-cd1-staging2", "cf-cd1", "cf-cd1-sic-staging", "cf-cd1-sagdf- 
staging"]

line_compile = re.compile('^(?!.*(ab1-canary|cd1-staging|cf-ab1-canary)).*$')

matched = []

for line in lines:
  if  line_compile.match(line):
     matched.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

As always with RegEx, there's many possible solutions. I came up with one on the fly but you could argue that it's overfitted to that dataset and not very generalized.

```
^cf-\w\w\d(-[hs][oia][tcg].+?)?$
```

I simply wrote all the "allowed" letters in square brackets until the undesired matches weren't possible anymore. Also, I put the second half in ()? so that the two short entries are also matched.

Comment: The +? part means it's non-greedy matching, which isn't necessary here, but it's a good habit to use it by default unless you really want greedy matching.